# Get the hyperlink and its text value using google docs

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, google-docs, google-apps, google-docs-api

I hope everyone is in good health.

My main goal
So main goal was to get the hyperlink and the text linked with it. I initially used code as below :

```
var ekArr = [];
function myFunction() {

var doc= DocumentApp.getActiveDocument();
var isCell4Blank1 = doc.getBlob().getDataAsString();

var data = Utilities.parseCsv(isCell4Blank1);
var linku = doc.getBody().getTables()[0].getCell(2,1);
var t = doc.getBody().getTables()[0].getCell(2,1).getText();
Logger.log("link is.   " + linku);
// Logger.log(doc.getBody().getText());
for(var find in data){
var fi = data[find].toString().includes("http");
if(fi===true){
var newArr = data[find].toString().split(" ");
var output = newArr[1].replace("(","").replace(")","").replace(">>>>","")
ekArr.push(output);
}


}
var tex = doc.getBody().getText();
var fo = tex.split(ekArr[0]);
Logger.log(tex);

doc.getBody().getTables()[0].getCell(2,2).setText(ekArr);
doc.getBody().getTables()[0].getCell(2,3).setText(t);
Logger.log(ekArr);
return ekArr;
}
```

I need to extract the links and content from the cells of a table.
From above code I am able to extract the links however I am not able to extract the text linked with it.

Also I have another code which helped me to extract the links and text but from googlesheets. As I am new to google docs I want to modify the below code according to google docs.

```
          function sheetFunction() {
          var sheet= SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();
          var isCell4Blank1 = sheet.getRange("A1").isBlank();
         if (!isCell4Blank1) {

            var linkData = 
   sheet.getRange("A1").getRichTextValue().getRuns().reduce((ar, e) => {

                 var url = e.getLinkUrl();
   Logger.log(url);
            if (url) {
               var color = e.getTextStyle().getForegroundColor();
              var startIndex = e.getStartIndex();
             var endIndex = e.getEndIndex();
               var text = e.getText()
          ar.push(color);
         ar.push(text);
         ar.push(startIndex);
          ar.push(endIndex);
       ar.push(url);
                 }
                 return ar;
             }, [])
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

### Use the methods [getText()](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/document/text#gettext) and [getLinkUrl()](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/document/equation-function?hl=en#getLinkUrl())

Sample based on your first code snippet:

```js
function myFunction() {  
  var doc = DocumentApp.getActiveDocument();
  var linku = doc.getBody().getTables()[0].getCell(2,1);
  Logger.log("link text is:   " + linku.getText());
  Logger.log("link is:   " + linku.getLinkUrl());
}
```